# base64EncodedStringWithOptions in Swift fails with compile error

Tags: ios, swift, base64

```
let dataStr = data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(options: Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
```

Doesn't compile with "Use of unresolved identifier 'Encoding64CharacterLineLength'"
When I just change the param to zero with

```
let dataStr = data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(options: 0)
```

It gives even stranger error: "Cannot convert the expression of type 'String!' to type 'String!'" I found a way to init NSString with NSData (however, I still can't get the difference between String and NSString), but I'm really curious why these two lines of code don't work.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Unless explicitly given an external name, first argument of a method in Swift is not a named argument. Therefore you should be doing: `data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(x)` without the `options:` part.

If you actually look at the argument type, `NSDataBase64EncodingOptions`, you'll notice that it is a struct conforming to `RawOptionSet` with static variables for option constants. Therefore to use them you should do: `NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength`

The `NSDataBase64EncodingOptions` struct (or `RawOptionSet` in general) is also not convertible from integer literals (like `0`). But it does conform to `NilLiteralConvertible` so if you don't want any options you can pass `nil`.

Putting it together:

```
let dataStr = data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
```

or

```
let dataStr = data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil)
```

**Swift3.0**

```
let dataStr = data.base64EncodedString(options: [])
```

Comment: Looks like as of Xcode 7 beta 4 passing the nil does not compile anymore. The documentation says `Use zero or one of the following...` but passing 0 also doesn't compile. What worked for me was `NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0)` if you don't want to use any options

Comment: For Swift 2.x use: `let dataStr = data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])` In general options can now be provided as an array.

Comment: For Swift 3 use: ```data.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)```

Answer (score 19):

For Swift 2.x use an array for options:

```
let dataStr = data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([.Encoding64CharacterLineLength])
let dataStr = data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
```

Comment: Using an empty array resolved my issue with Auto Subscriptions receipt Validation

Answer (score 6):

For swift 3.0+ use this ,

```
var dataStr = data.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
```

Comment: its awesome..thanx

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3.x**

```
let fileStream = fileData?.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions.init(rawValue: 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to put in the "options:" identifier in the argument. You DO have to specify that Encoding64CharacterLineLength is a static member of NSDataBase64EncodingOptions, like so:

```
var dataStr = data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
```

Comment: the encoding option is now ```.lineLength64Characters```

Answer (score 0):

```
let dataStr = data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.allZeros)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the default parameter value is set be an empty array…

```
/// Returns a Base-64 encoded string.
///
/// - parameter options: The options to use for the encoding. Default value is `[]`.
/// - returns: The Base-64 encoded string.
@inlinable public func base64EncodedString(options: Data.Base64EncodingOptions = []) -> String
```

you just need to call

```
let dataStr = data.base64EncodedString()
```