# iOS take a photo and convert to Base64 String

Tags: ios, image, swift, base64

I have a simple photo taking application and I need it to very simply convert imageData into base64 encoded string, this is what I do:

```
if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo){
    stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection) { (imageDataSampleBuffer, error) in
        self.imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageDataSampleBuffer)
        let base64String = self.imageData.base64EncodedDataWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
        print(base64String)
    }
}
```

I would expect this to produce string similar to something like this:

```
%2F9j%2F4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD%2F2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHB...
```

However what I get looks something like this:

```
<2f396a2f 34414151 536b5a4a 52674142 41514141 53414249 4141442f 345142...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Just to clarify, I am taking the picture for sure and I am able to use:

```
self.image = UIImage(data: self.imageData) 
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.image, self, nil, nil)
```

To save it into device, so photo is definitely there.

Comment: Try this way : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769074/base64encodedstringwithoptions-in-swift-fails-with-compile-error

Comment: worked like a charm, thank you mate

Answer (score 2):

Thank you [@johny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3134130/johny-kumar), your answer was correct!

Solution was to use this:

```
base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
```

Instead of this:

```
base64EncodedDataWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
```